# C++ composition using smart pointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, composition

I am following the design of a Game Object architecture [presented by Marcin Chady](http://www.gdcvault.com/play/1911/%E2%80%8E).
As a quick summary, the Game Object class can contain multiple Attribute and Behaviour subclass instances. Game objects are also contained within a Scene class. This diagram may clarify things:

[image]

The Behaviour subclasses need to be able to access their parent Game Object class. This is required as the behaviours need to be able to read and write to various attributes and subscribe to receive events from the game object. Some behaviours may also need to access their parent game object's scene so that they can instantiate other game objects.

I am presently using shared pointers and weak pointers. For example, the Game Object class contains a `vector<shared_ptr<Attribute>>` and `vector<shared_ptr<Behaviour>>`. The Behaviour and Attribute classes then both contain a `weak_ptr<GameObject>`. This breaks the reference cycle.

Now, if a behaviour wants to access the scene, it needs to perform a few nested weak pointer locks:

```
if (std::shared_ptr<GameObject> sharedGameObject = GetGameObject().lock())
{
    if (std::shared_ptr<Scene> sharedScene = sharedGameObject->GetScene().lock())
    {
        // Do something with the scene.
    }
}
```

This can get a little messy. If we need to access the Application class then 3 nested locks are required. This is obviously not required when using raw pointers. Am I using the right smart pointers? If I am, is there anything that I can do to tidy this up or is this something that I'm just going to have to live with?

Comment: One possible solution:  Remove the weak_ptr objects entirely.  Ideally the Behavior and Attribute objects shouldn't need to access the GameObject at all, but if they absolutely must, pass in a GameObject pointer (or reference) to them as an argument to the methods you call on them.

Comment: Why are you using smart pointers here.  There doesn't seem to be a need.

Comment: You could code it with the shared pointer loops, then have a shutdown method to be called when you want object to go away. In the shutdown method you can reset the shared pointers to allow the target objects to be deleted.  You'd probably still need to test the pointers before using them to be sure they have not been reset, but that avoids the performance hit of the weak pointer lock.

Comment: @Jeremy The Game Object class only calls the Behaviour::Update function. The behaviour classes generally have quite a few more functions, many of which need access to the game object.

Comment: @JamesKanze What's the alternative? If I just use raw pointers then there is no clear sign of ownership.

Comment: @DaleWilson I'm not really looking at performance at this stage.

Comment: How about replacing just the weak_ptr's with raw pointers?  As long as you can guarantee that the Behavior and Attribute objects will be destroyed before the GameObject is (e.g. by the GameObject destructor) the raw pointers will always be safe to use.

Comment: @Homar And?  Do you have any ownership to be concerned with?  If so, is it clearly obvious?  In such cases, you don't need smart pointers.  If the pointers are only used for navigation, they should be raw pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want smart pointers here.  From a first guess,
based on the design hierarchy (and the names):

- If this is a typical hierarchy, there will be only one
  `Application`, which will not be allocated dynamically, but will
  be a local variable in `main`.  So there would never be a smart
  pointer to it.
- All of the `Scene` belong to `Application`, so it's clear from the design
  who owns what.  In both cases, it's a 1 to n relationship, which
  means that the pointers in the owning object will need to be in
  containers.  You could use `std::unique_ptr`, but it doesn't
  really seem necessary; in fact, it seems slightly obfuscating:
  to delete an object, you don't use `delete`, you `erase` it from
  the container.  (On the other hand, with raw pointers, you do
  have to both delete and remove it from the container.  It's
  largely up to you here, although I tend to prefer the simplicity
  of raw pointers.)
- If these classes represent what I think they do, `GameObject`
  come and go as a result of external events.  This is a typical
  case where none of the existing smart pointers are relevant.
  I would guess that most of the `GameObject` are created by
  `Scene` in response to an event; some might be created by other
  `GameObject`.  But once created, they manage their own lifetime,
  and will probably be deleted by a `delete this` in their event
  handler.  (Of course, all objects interested in their lifetime
  will have to register as observers, using the observer pattern.
  But this will be the case anyway.)
- The `EventDispatcher` doubtlessly has pointers to any objects
  interested in events, but these are for navigation.  They should
  *not* be smart pointers.  It is the responsibility of each
  object to enrol and disenrol with the `EventDispatcher`
  according to the events it's interested in—rather
  obviously, it will disenrol for everything in the destructor,
  because dead objects aren't interested in any events, but it
  will also (probably) enrol and disenrol at various other times
  as well.

Note that the necessity of a `weak_ptr` is generally a good
indication that reference counted pointers are not the solution
you're looking for.

Comment: `delete this` is almost always a bug. At best it's undefined behavior. If you need it, you'd need to implement some sort of `deleteLater` functionality that gets invoked once the execution exits the object to be deleted.

Comment: @KubaOber Yes, my `GameObject` class has a `dead` boolean flag which I use to remove all of the dead game objects from the scene at the end of the scene update.

Comment: @KubaOber `delete this` is probably the most frequent case.  It's certainly not undefined behavior, and it's what corresponds closest to "true" OO design.  And there's no need for a `deleteLater`.

Comment: @Homar Why do it that way?  That just introduced additional complexity, and since in a game, you almost certainly don't need to be able to roll back, there's no reason for an object not to do `delete this` when it receives the appropriate event.  Despite Kuba's comments, `delete this` is a legal and well established idiom.  In applications which don't need to support transactional roll-back (you can't undelete when rolling back), it should be the most frequent case of `delete`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: OK, so it's not undefined behavior, but if you ask me, [it might as well be](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/delete-this.html). The compiler doesn't check all those "100% sure" items I linked to. It's a surefire way of shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @KubaOber That's really a bad entry in the FAQ, because all of the objections apply to any pointer, not just to `this`.  Deleting this is a standard idiom, widely used in well written code.  It's no more likely to result in your shooting yourself in the foot than any other delete.

Comment: @JamesKanze: It's just like any other delete, except that it must be in the tail position in the *entire* call stack of methods in `this`. Since it requires *even more care* than just a `delete`, saying that it's "no more likely" to lead to bad things is somewhat at odds with reality, IMHO. Somehow, I've never ever had to resort to it, but I've used the `deleteLater` idiom very often. At least it can play ball with smart pointers. `delete this` only plays nice with intrusive smart pointers.

Comment: @KubaOber Exactly the same thing holds for all use of `delete`: no function above the function executing `delete` can use the object after calling the function.  This is just basic lifetime management.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need any smart-pointers here at all, assuming:

- that the `GameObject` object truly *owns* `Attribute` & `Behavior` objects, or
- that the `GameObject` object's lifetime will always be longer than the `Attribute` & `Behavior` objects' lifetime.

Or considering your code-example, think of these questions: What would the `else` stanzas do?  Would they ever get executed?  I think the answer would be: "They only do failure/error detection & reporting", and "No, I can't imagine so".

You should switch to internal references to the `GameObject` class, using `std::reference_wrapper<T>` if you want it to be slightly more modern C++ looking, or raw-pointers, or raw-references.